# Rebuild JTable structure in Table architecture with separate row header table

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtable

I have three different table structures, each of it in a `JScrollPane`. Each table is implemented with separate row headers that don't scroll along horizontally (very similar to how it was done [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ArowheadercolumnwiththeTableColumnModel.htm)). As in the link, I wrote two custom `TableColumnModels` that drop either the first row or all but the first row. One `JTable` only contains the row header column and the other containing the remaining data share the same `TableModel`. However, I'm struggling with the `autocreateColumnsFromModel` flag and the respective method `createDefaultColumnsFromModel()`. When I add a new entry to a table (in my GUI by clicking a button that envokes that functionality), the other tables have to be updated (hence, `AbstractTableModel.fireTableStructureChanged()` is called). My problem is now though that as the tables are rebuilt, the row header column is re-added as a regular column to the table (since in my opinion, `createDefaultColumnsFromModel()` rebuilds the table using only the `TableModel` and ignoring the `TableColumnModels` constraints of which column to drop and which one to use).

I did find [this article](http://www.chka.de/swing/table/row-headers/JTable.html) interesting that talks about exactly that issue, stating that

> This requires that you manage the TableColumns of the main table on your own, otherwise JTable will re-introduce the header column into the main table

..., which is exactly what is happening for me. What would this mean though, to manage the `TableColumns` of the main table on my own? How do I rebuild the table structure by using the `TableColumnModel` that would take care of which columns to display in the table?

Comment: FireTableStructureChanged instructs the JTable that the column and data have changed and all previously cached data should be discarded, it's probably not what you really want, perhaps rowInserted would be more suitable

Comment: The issue is it's not always a row that's inserted. Sometimes it's a column that needs to be updated in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem didn't lie within the `fireTableStructureChanged()` method or the `createDefaultColumnsFromModel()`. But the `TableColumnModel`, whose `addColumn()` method was specific for the rowHeaderTable and the mainTable (see [this implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ArowheadercolumnwiththeTableColumnModel.htm)) needed to be instantiated anew. Thats because the flag that checks whether only the first column or only everything but the first column should be added to the table needed to be reset.
With this new `tableColumnModel`, `createDefaultColumnsFromModel()` can be called and the tables successfully updated.